# Highlight substring within substring in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, substring, highlight

I was trying to highlight substring within string using start and end index. But i am facing issue while highlighting overlapped substring.
e.g.

I have a `text` and an `array` for highlighting.

Is there any way, how can I avoid the overlapping tags.
I tried with `regex` match of the substring, but couldn't able to solve it.

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-river-9wjidd)

```js
let tagObject = {
  "text": "I am asking a question in stackoverflow",
  "tags": [{
      start: 0,
      end: 1,
      value: "I",
      tag: "TAG1"
    },
    {
      start: 0,
      end: 4,
      value: "I am",
      tag: "TAG2"
    },
    {
      start: 5,
      end: 22,
      value: "asking a question",
      tag: "TAG3"
    },
    {
      start: 14,
      end: 22,
      value: "question",
      tag: "TAG4"
    },
    {
      start: 14,
      end: 25,
      value: "question in",
      tag: "TAG5"
    }
  ]
}

const color = {
  outer: "color: #1d39c4; background: #f0f5ff; border-color: #adc6ff;",
  inner: "background: #adc6ff;",
  bg: "#f0f5ff"
}

const createStyledString = (obj) => {
  let {
    text,
    tags
  } = obj;
  tags.sort((a, b) => b.start - a.start);
  tags.forEach(t => {
    const {
      start,
      end,
      value,
      tag
    } = t;
    text = text.substring(0, start) +
      `<span contenteditable="false" data-action="${value}---${start}---${end}---${color.bg}---${tag}" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" name="tag" class="outer" style="${color.outer}">${value}<span class="ne-c-inner" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" data-action="${value}---${start}---${end}---${color.bg}---${tag}" style="${color.inner}">${tag}</span></span>` +
      text.substring(end)
  });
  return text;
}
document.body.innerHTML=createStyledString(tagObject)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet, can you make it a [mcve]?

Comment: What means *"avoid the overlapping tags"*? Should they be split? Encompassed one into the other? Can you give an example of the desired?

Comment: I mean overlapping intervals of ```start``` and ```end``` index of the substrings.

Comment: OK, I see that they are overlapping, but what is the expected result? Should the tags be treeified or split in series when overlapping?

Comment: Also, why are you using `value` property if you already have the `start` and `end` integers?

Comment: encompassed one into the other,

Comment: I am using ```value``` to highlight in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main problems in your approach.

1. First of all, if you have nested values you are appending them more than once.
2. Second, you are treating the start and end positions as if they didn't change after the string was modified.

So a possible solution would be the following:

1. Don't nest values, just take the same substring once again.
2. Keep track of the real position as well as the initial, "virtual", position, and use it to insert the code in the correct place.

Here's a working snippet.

```js
let tagObject = {
  "text": "I am asking a question in stackoverflow",
  "tags": [{
      start: 0,
      end: 1,
      value: "I",
      tag: "TAG1"
    },
    {
      start: 0,
      end: 4,
      value: "I am",
      tag: "TAG2"
    },
    {
      start: 5,
      end: 22,
      value: "asking a question",
      tag: "TAG3"
    },
    {
      start: 14,
      end: 22,
      value: "question",
      tag: "TAG4"
    },
    {
      start: 14,
      end: 25,
      value: "question in",
      tag: "TAG5"
    }
  ]
}

const color = {
  outer: "color: #1d39c4; background: #f0f5ff; border-color: #adc6ff;",
  inner: "background: #adc6ff;",
  bg: "#f0f5ff"
}

const createStyledString = (obj) => {
  let {
    text,
    tags
  } = obj;
  tags.sort((a, b) => b.start - a.start);
  
  // TO KEEP TRACK OF INSERTED TEXT
  let insertedAmmount = []
  
  tags.forEach(t => {
    const {
      start,
      end,
      value,
      tag
    } = t;
    
    // COMPUTE THE REAL START AND END POSITIONS
    // TAKING INSERTED TEXT INTO ACCOUNT
    let realStart = start
    let realEnd = end
    for(let idx in insertedAmmount){
      if(idx < start){
        realStart += insertedAmmount[idx]
      }
      if(idx <= end){
        realEnd += insertedAmmount[idx]
      }
    }
    
    let pre = `<span contenteditable="false" data-action="${value}---${start}---${end}---${color.bg}---${tag}" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" name="tag" class="outer" style="${color.outer}">`
    
    let pos = `<span class="ne-c-inner" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" data-action="${value}---${start}---${end}---${color.bg}---${tag}" style="${color.inner}">${tag}</span></span>`
    
    // UPDATE THE INFORMATION ABOUT INSERTED TEXT
    insertedAmmount[start] = (insertedAmmount[start] || 0) + pre.length
    insertedAmmount[end] = (insertedAmmount[end] || 0) + pos.length
    
    // DON'T INSERT DIRECTLY THE VALUE BUT THE ALREADY EXISTENT TEXT
    text = text.substring(0, realStart) 
      + pre
      + text.substring(realStart, realEnd)
      + pos
      + text.substring(realEnd)
  });
  return text;
}
document.body.innerHTML=createStyledString(tagObject)
```

Comment: I had to run but glad to see this sorted. Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks Miguel and Roko :):)